# How can I import Rinkeby account to metamask after deploying my contract to Rinkeby test network?

Tags: go-ethereum, metamask, rinkeby, import

I finished deploying(compiled and migrated) my contract to Rinkeby test network. So, now I'm trying to go to MetaMask and clicked on Rinkeby TestNet and don't know what to do after. How do I get my Rinkeby's private key or json file to import to metamask? All I can see is ["account Address", "account Address", "account Address"] when I put "eth.accounts" on my geth console.

Answer (score 0):

Open Metamask and on top right corner, second last option is for changing account. There the last one is for importing account. You can import account by

- importing the raw private key.
- importing the JSON file which contains the encrypted private key.